# Is it OK to sell swag?

Tags: ethics, company-policy, compensation

I received a piece of swag from my employer; all employees received it.  It's branded with the company logo.  I have no use for it; neither does my wife.

As far as I can tell, the item actually retails for about $200 (USD).

Would it be unethical to resell it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with navigating the workplace.

Comment: @MaskedMan My first guess would be that the swag came from OP's employer, in which case it seems very much related to navigating the workplace, in that we can probably say whether or not this is something one is likely to get reprimanded for if the company finds out (no idea whether or not that's opinion-based though).

Comment: @dukeling Ok, that wasn't clear from the first version, although it was probably implied. Nonetheless, sounds company-specific to me. For example, my company gifted me a watch (with a company logo). Now that watch technically belongs to me, since it is gifted, and I can do what I please with it. Will my company care if I sell it in the flea market? Probably not. Will they think very highly of me for doing so? Certainly not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about ethics and swag, which is just odd

Comment: Unless the "swag" is a computerized device that contains sensitive company information (I have been given pre-loaded, branded USB sticks, for example, granted they wouldn't go for $200) then I don't see a problem selling it.  If it *does* (or *might*) contain sensitive information, then make sure to wipe it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not unethical, but it might be unwise, at least until you're no longer working there. If your colleagues learned that you'd sold it, they might think you don't value the firm's comrade, or that you don't really like the firm, or maybe that you're in such economic distress that you're selling your personal belongings. Non of those are particularly good standings among your peers.